# Java BufferedReader FileReader issue

Tags: java, try-catch, bufferedreader, filereader

So I have the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Plagiarism {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

        if  (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No files input");
        }
        else if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
                    simplify (reader);
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println ("Error reading from file");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void simplify(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
        String line = null;

        line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
            line = line.toLowerCase();
        }    
    }

}
```

The problem with this code is that it compiles, but when i run it and add in the 2 arguments in command line eg. Java Plagiarism text1.txt text2.txt. EDIT: When I run this it just doesn't do anything or even finish, it's like it's stuck somewhere.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: add `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` in your `catch` clause to learn what the exception is.

Comment: Start by not catching `Exception` but a more specific one. `Exception` also catches `RuntimeException` and derivates, therefore all unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Print your Stacktrace (e.printStackTrace()).

Comment: Where are your text1.txt and text2.txt?. Are you getting FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Sorry guys I edited the question. The text files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the files at once (you would need to use threading to do that).

The issue is in your `simplify` method.

```
line = input.readLine();
while (line != null) {
```

... should become:

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
```

The reason for this is that you are calling `readLine` only once, and iterating only over the first line's value otherwise.

With the proper `while` loop you pipe the value of the `readLine` call to the non-`null` condition after assigning it to your `line` variable.

You can then do whatever you want with the `line` `String` you manipulated in your `while` loop, such as adding it to an `array` or `Collection`, as you suggested in your comment.

For instance:

```
public static List<String> simplify(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        result.add(line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase());
    }    
    return result;
}
```

... then in your `main` method...

```
List<String> foo = simplify(reader);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. With the second issue though, how do you mean? This code should surely work? If it cannot work how can I get it to work with the readers? Thanks

Comment: I see. I don't want to EDIT the file though - I'd want to put the 2 text documents into arrays first then edit those arrays, which is what im attempting.

Comment: @user3364788 aha my bad. Then you **don't** need writers. Let me edit again.

Comment: Surely "line" should be filled though after this while loop? When I try to print "line" it's still null...

Comment: @user3364788 it's filled **inside** the `while` loop! Each line you read until `line` is `null`. Outside the loop it **will** be `null` as `null` equality is the loop-exiting condition.

Comment: Ahh I understand this. Now, the array, do I have to first initialise this in the while loop? If i do it outside the while loop, ie. before it, the program won't compile as it cannot find the array.

Comment: @user3364788 you can safely initialize your `array` or `Collection` outside the `while` loop, but **not** outside the method's scope. What I would probably do is initializing within the method, outside the loop, then change the method's return type to that `array` or `Collection`'s type and return it after the loop has completed. That way, you'll be able to reuse it in your `main` method (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit, much appreciated. I tried this code and ran it.. but nothing seemed to happen. Nothing printing to the cmd nor any edits of the text files. Is it meant to? I want to test it's actually working first before I go further.

Comment: You're welcome. The code I posted only assigns the value to the reference but prints nothing. In order to print something, add printing statements in your loop, or iterate over the values of your `List` and print each.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be removing spaces, and it's printing them out on a new line every time. Prferably want them on one line and spaces gotten rid of. Can I ask for your help once again, kind Sir? @Mena

Comment: @user3364788 sure I can help you but this is out of scope - ask a new question. It'll also give a chance for more folks to answer, and for you to get different opinions.

Comment: Sure, thanks, new question has been asked. Once again, thanks for your help, I'd +1 you if I could!

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: When I run this it just doesn't do anything or even finish, it's like it's stuck somewhere.

Which is perfectly normal. Look at your `while` loop:

```
    while (line != null) {
        line = line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
        line = line.toLowerCase();
    }
```

`line` will never be null here. You should:

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    // etc
```

You have a more fundamental problem: your program will never work correctly if your goal is to replace lines in the input files...

Try this instead:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+");

private static void simplify(final String fileName)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    final Path tempfile = Files.createTempFile(fileName.getFileName(), "tmp");
    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
        final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempfile);
    ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = PATTERN.matcher(line).replaceAll("").toLowerCase();
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.flush();
    }
    Files.move(tempfile, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't what I need though I don't think. Fundamentally I am comparing both the text documents, so I am not replacing the content in the files, but instead using it and then editing the content in arrays.